# how to scroll lock first column of a report style listview in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, listview

I want to lock the first column of a report style listview from scrolling horizontally.  I'm programming in C++ using Win32 (no .NET).  This functionality does not appear to be available in the standard listview.  Any suggestions on how this can be accomplished with C++/Win32?  I've seen the suggestion of using a DataGridView in .NET, but I'm not using .NET...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the only thing I can think of is to use two abutting listview controls, one with the single column that never scrolls and the other with all the other columns. Not an ideal solution but there's no way to make the standard listview behave this way.

Alternatively, you could just write your own listview-like control.

Comment: That's the only way I can think of and the method that Process Explorer uses.